# GNUplot plot using a variable with data columns

Tags: gnuplot

This seems like a real noob question but I haven't been able to figure out how to do it.
This gnuplot line:

```
pineIslandSoundTides = system('/opt/local/bin/tide -em SsMm -tf "%H:%M" -l "Captiva Island, Pine Island Sound, Florida" ')
```

outputs the variable 'pineIslandSoundTides' containing this data:

```
2017-04-11 02:09   Full Moon
2017-04-11 02:25   1.54 feet  High Tide
2017-04-11 08:23   0.51 feet  Low Tide
2017-04-11 14:00   1.88 feet  High Tide
2017-04-11 21:12   0.06 feet  Low Tide
2017-04-12 03:04   1.47 feet  High Tide
2017-04-12 08:44   0.64 feet  Low Tide
2017-04-12 14:17   1.97 feet  High Tide
2017-04-12 21:46  -0.03 feet  Low Tide
2017-04-13 03:44   1.39 feet  High Tide
```

What is the format to do: plot 'pineIslandSoundTides' u 1:2:3, etc

Answer (score 0):

The gnuplot code

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"
set format x "%Y-%m-%d\n%H:%M"
set xtics 12*60*60               # draw tic labels every 12 hours
unset key
set ylabel "Tide level in feet"
plot "pineIslandSoundTides" u 1:3 with points, "" u 1:3:(stringcolumn(5)) with labels offset 0,-1
```

creates [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJWbB.png). Gnuplot automatically ignores the first line in your data file that does not have a valid tide level.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, what your actual problem is, using that data or the time settings. Concerning the time settings you already got an answer.

Plotting the data from a system call can be done using  `plot '< systemcall'`:

```
pineIslandSoundTides = '/opt/local/bin/tide -em SsMm -tf "%H:%M" -l "Captiva Island, Pine Island Sound, Florida" '

plot '< '.pineIslandSoundTides u 1:3
```